# Routing between two

Tags: networking, windows-10, routing, ipv4

I have the following network setup:

[image]

From Laptop I can ping any IP in the 192.168.2.0/24 network and I have internet access. On Tower PC I can ping any IP in the 192.168.2.0/24 network (including 192.168.2.1) but I cannot ping any other addresses in either the 192.168.0.0/24 network or the internet at large.

This is my routing table (it's the default):

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.108      4
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.0.108    258
    192.168.0.108  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.108    258
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.108    258
      192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.2.1    257
      192.168.2.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.1    257
    192.168.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.1    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.2.1    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.0.108    258
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.1    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.108    258
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

I have tried a few static routes but cannot figure it out and any help would be welcome.

Comment: Yes. My bad. Just corrected the typo.

Comment: Yes, the Tower PC has default gateway set to 2.1. It is assigned by the DHCP server running on the Laptop and bound to the eth interface. And as I said from the Tower PC I can ping 192.168.2.1, so the address is resolved at Ethernet level by ARP.

Comment: Hi @Facebook, the two rules made the packets flow from one network to the other. But then the ping from the Tower to the TP Link wasn't returning anything and I added a rule there to route to 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.0.108 and then it worked. :-) Please feel free to answer the question with the information you gave in the comments and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [route](https://ss64.com/nt/route.html) to add network routes to the **Windows** routing table to pass traffic between the two subnets and network interfaces—below are two quick examples.

```
ROUTE ADD 192.168.2.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.108 
ROUTE ADD 192.168.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.2.1
```

*This will give the two network interfaces on the laptop (Ethernet and Wi-Fi), a route to get to the other subnet between the two—but **test and adjust accordingly 
 for your needs**.*

---

### Further Resources

- [Route](https://ss64.com/nt/route.html)

Comment: I also used the “route add -p” switch to make the rule permanent across reboots.