# Routing between two isolated systems without VPN

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router

Weird scenario for you:

I have two Raspberry Pis running Raspbian 8 (jessie) connected to each other by a cross-over cable between their Ethernet ports. The Ethernet port on unit A is statically configured as 10.5.10.1. The Ethernet port on unit B is statically configured as 10.5.10.2. Subnet mask for the Ethernet interface is 255.255.255.0 - /24.

Both units are running the host access point daemon (hostapd) and DHCP server on their Wifi interface (wlan0). They each have a unique SSID:  unit A is “raspiA” while unit B is “raspiB”.  Unit A runs on channel 1. Unit B runs on channel 11.

The wlan0 adapter on unit A is statically assigned as 10.10.1.1. The DHCP server on unit A serves addresses in the range of 10.10.1.50 - 10.10.1.250. The wlan0 adapter on unit B is statically assigned as 10.10.2.1. The DHCP server on unit B seven addresses in the range of 10.10.2.50 - 10.10.2.250. Subnet masks for the wlan0 adapters are both /24.

The systems are completely isolated - there is no connection to the Internet.

Both systems run a process which runs an HTTP server on port 80, available from either interface (eth0 or wlan0).

I want a client connected to the access point on system A to be able to access the process on system B on 10.10.1.2.

I want a client connected to the access point on system B to be able to access the process on system A on 10.10.2.2.

```
[Client 1]         [Unit A              ]        [Unit B ]
10.10.1.50 —wifi—> 10.10.1.2 —> 10.5.10.1 —eth—> 10.5.10.2
```

And...

```
[Unit A ]        [Unit B              ]         [Client 2]
10.5.10.1 <—eth— 10.5.10.2 <— 10.10.2.2 <—wifi— 10.10.2.50
```

What is the best way to make this happen?

Comment: Please add the subnet masks to your IP addresses in your post. Since you are using class-a address ranges, it will be hard for anyone to give you an answer not knowing if the 10.5.x.x and 10.10.x.x networks are continuous networks or separate.

Comment: With out a router in-between the two /24 networks this isn't going to work. You may be better off bridging the two connections. I.e put one device at x.x.x.1 and the other on x.x.x.254. if they have to be on separate ipv4 networks there has to be a routing device.

Comment: Let me know if that works for you I'll add it as the answer

Comment: @Tim_Stewart - is there anything required to create the bridge using the eth0 devices? I tried putting everything on the same /24 but that didn't help. (Apologies if that's not what you intended for me to try - I'm a bit out of my depth on this one.)

Comment: That's ok, you would set it like this. Client1  10.10.10.20 /24 > unitb 10.10.10.1 > unita > 10.10.10.254 > client 2 10.10.10.30 /24. I believe you would still need IP forwarding enabled on the two "units".

Comment: https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/bridge

Comment: @Tim_Stewart, unit A and B are the routers between the two networks.

Comment: No, lol they are rasberry pi's. They won't route traffic like that by default.

Comment: I came to the conclusion that I was going about this the wrong way. I've revised the approach to use a simpler IP scheme, NAT, and a single route statement and it seems to be working. If it holds up, I'll post the answer for anyone else who needs this sort of config.

Comment: @Tim_Steward, what the hardware is does not matter... it's a linux system which is *very* much capable of being a router.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is enable ip forwarding on A and B ( as root ):

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

Comment: no joy. I enabled ip forwarding on both systems and was unable to access the "other" machine's http server on any address.

Comment: @StevenSokol, are each of A and B the default route for the clients on their respective networks?

Comment: I'd say maybe just give him the `route add` to add per the example IP networks he provided. Maybe ensuring the route is persistent too exist even after a power cycle of either the PI's. I assume he'd need a route on both to point back to the appropriate gateway. I posted a similar answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1260326/routing-between-two/1260655#1260655 but for Windows for example.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT, the PIs don't need a route since they are directly connected to one another.  What needs a route are the nodes on the two networks.  I had assumed they would just have a default route to their respective PIs, but if not, then they would all need an explicit route directing traffic to the other network to their PI.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a configuration that works. It allows a client to join either network and have access to both systems. It also does not require routing, which is important as any scheme which assigns a router (default gateway) causes mobile clients (iOS, Android) to prioritize their Wifi interface over their 4G interface, cutting off Internet access.

I simplified the IP scheme by moving everything into the same /24 (class c) segment. I set up bridges between the eth0 interface and the wlan0 interface on both systems. The bridge on system A was assigned .1 and the bridge on system B was assigned .2. All services provided by the system are bound to / available on the bridge address.

I adjusted the DHCP daemons on each system to serve a different range from the /24 (i.e. system A was .50 - .149 and system B was 150 - 249). Because the systems are bridged together (i.e. all on the same segment) any DHCP request turns into a race, with both daemons responding. Since both offers will be in the same /24, it doesn’t matter which one “wins”.

This creates a certain form of redundancy. If either system dies, the clients can re-associate with the access point on the other system. If the application on either system crashes, the clients can connect to the instance on the other system. The two systems can also monitor each other, mirror configuration, and cross-check data.

One limitation of this approach is that the clients must know that the applications are available on .1 and .2. A future iteration may include some sort of MDSN / Avahi support that allows clients to discover servers automatically.

Steps:

1. Install `bridge-utils`, `hostapd`, and `isc-dhcp-server`
2. Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

   1. Either add or uncomment `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`
3. In `/etc/network/interfaces`:

   1. Mark both eth0 and wlan0 as manual
   2. Add the br0 bridge with the desired static network configuration
   3. Add only the eth0 interface (the wlan0 will be added by hostapd)
4. Edit `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

   1. Exclude eth0 and wlan0 from DHCP by adding `denyinterfaces eth0 wlan0` at the bottom.
5. Edit `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`:

   1. Set the `INTERFACES` value to `br0`
6. Edit `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`:

   1. Create a new subnet entry
   2. Add some number of client-available IPs to the range
   3. Do NOT add "option routers"
7. Edit `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`:

   1. Add `bridge=br0` at the bottom

Repeat this process for the other system, altering the IP assigned to the bridge (step 2.2) and the range of addresses served by the DHCP server (step 5.2). Connect the Ethernet ports with a cable. Reboot. Voila - redundant, flat network.