# Two NIC with two subnets - access both from each other?

Tags: networking, routing, static-routes

I have a NAS with two NIC's.

I have my normal home network with an Apple Airport on subnet 10.0.1.x. My NAS (a QNAP) is on NIC#1 @ 10.0.1.50 with its own switch. All is good there.

I have NIC#2 set up on its own subnet 10.0.2.x with DHCP running and the NIC on 10.0.2.1. My plan is to have IP cameras on this separate network and again it's own switch (POE).

Question: How do I set this up so that I can access the 10.0.2.x from the 10.0.1.x main network?

I am not super network savvy but is it as simple as changing the network mask to 255.255.0.0 or something like that?

**UPDATE**

[image]
So here is the routing table options for this unit.  Not sure how I set this up.

**UPDATE 2**

Revised Question: How do I set my routes via this GUI up so that I can access the 10.0.2.x from the 10.0.1.x main network and vice versa?

Comment: See my answer here as something like this may help: https://superuser.com/questions/1260326/routing-between-two/1260655#1260655 For Linux look over https://linux.die.net/man/8/route rather than the Windows route command options.

Comment: Is the NAS running DHCP?  Can you enable routing or IP forwarding on this device?  You can change the network mask if you want, but if devices are physically "behind" the NAS then the NAS has to forward traffic and nothing "behind" it will get past the NAS without the NAS's help.

Comment: Both comments are helpful here - more so for me to understand the basics here.  I do have DHCP on the second NIC as I was going to set-up my cameras with DCHP assignments vs. having to hard code them.  I am trying to keep the camera traffic on the one network as they record direct on the NAS and don't really need internet access.  I really just want to be able to use the camera web GUI from the other main network.  I think IP routing is what I want but there is no direct web GUI on the NAS that I can see.

Comment: The NAS had a recent software update.  I can add static routes.  I am unsure what to add here to make this work.  The 10.0.1.x subnet is the normal home network with direct internet access etc. and where I will be accessing this from.  I just want to be able to access the 10.0.2.x devices and let them access the internet.

Comment: I am going to test this tonight - it may be as simple as this: 
ROUTE ADD 10.0.1.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.0.2.1 
ROUTE ADD 10.0.2.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.0.1.1

Comment: Note that for 10.0.1.*/24 to reach 10.0.2.*/24 (that includes answer packets), you either need routes on the default gateway of 10.0.1.* (probably your main home router), or you need routes on *all* of the devices in 10.0.1.*/24. These can be static routes, or you can distribute them via DHCP. This is not a problem for the 10.0.2.*/24, as the gateway (your NAS) is also the forwarding router.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that at least one device that is on both networks (probably the computer with two NICs) could be configured to route from one network to the other.

It is simpler to configure one larger network (such as would be created if you set the netmask to 255.255.0.0), so that is another option.

Routing makes sense if there are bandwidth limitations, or if you want to create a control / choke-point.

It looks like you want to set up routing.  You have a few devices you care about, and a few interfaces:

- NAS - 10.0.1.50
- IP camera - 10.0.2.50?
- Two-NIC computer (router?) - (NIC#2:10.0.2.1, NIC#1:10.0.1.?)
- AirPort - 10.0.1.1?

You'll need to configure the two-NIC computer to route between its two interfaces.  This depends on the OS, but shouldn't be a roadblock.

The IP camera can be configured (using DHCP) with NIC#2 of the router (10.0.2.1) as its default gateway, because that device sits between it and all other networks.

The NAS can be configured with the AirPort's IP as its default gateway, and the router's NIC#1 as its route to 10.0.2.0/24.

The router should probably be configured with the AirPort as its default gateway (it already knows about both directly connected networks, so it just needs to know how to get to the Internet / other networks)

You might configure the AirPort to route 10.0.2.0/24 traffic towards the router's NIC#1.  That could save you configuring the NAS individually, and allow all devices on the 10.0.1.0/24 network to reach 10.0.2.0/24 without additional configuration.  It may not work perfectly though; some equipment doesn't like to route out the same interface the packet came in.  There is another solution to that, but it is more complex.

Specific to the UI displayed:

> Revised Question: How do I set my routes via this GUI up so that I can
>   access the 10.0.2.x from the 10.0.1.x main network and vice versa?

- Destination: 10.0.2.0 (This is the IP portion of the destination network.)
- Netmask: 255.255.255.0 (This is the netmask portion of the destination network)
- Gateway: 10.0.1.? (The IP address of the device that routes to the destination network)
- Metric: (Shouldn't matter)
- Interface: (If you only have one active interface, choose that one. Otherwise, choose the interface that is closest to the gateway)

Rules to live by:

- A route consists of a network you are trying to reach, and a device on the same network you are on that will pass traffic towards that network you are trying to reach.  (And sometimes a metric, but don't worry about that at this scale)
- A default gateway is a fallback route / route of last resort for packets that aren't headed towards a network with a defined route.  Because of this, it doesn't need you to specify a network; just the IP address.
- A network can be expressed a variety of ways, including:

  - 1.2.3.0/24 - The first available IP address in the network, followed by a / and then the number of leading (most significant) bits that are consistent for all IP addresses in the network.
  - 1.2.3.0, netmask: 255.255.255.0 - The first available IP address in the network, followed by an IP address that has all bits set that are consistent for ip addresses in the network (e.g. /24 == 255.255.255.0, /16 == 255.255.0.0, /30 == 255.255.255.63)

Comment: I have a QNAP NAS with 4 NICs.  NIC 1 has a managed DLink switch on my Airport network connected to the internet (cable modem).  The Airport is running DHCP and I think you can set the subnet mask.  I can switch that to the NAS and it can run DHCP and I can set the mask there.

Comment: NIC 2 has a managed POE switch and the idea here was to segregate the cameras to it’s own network AND hardware so that all the camera bandwidth and traffic stays on that side - all recording on the NAS.  5 kids and iPads / laptops / Netflix can all stay on NIC 1.

I just need to get to the cameras to update them etc. and they need internet access from time to time.

Comment: I think routing is the way to go - I am not clear from that GUI what to enter.

The fall back would be the net mask and just jumper the two switches.  I could hard code IP’s on the camera network.